# Default Eclipse preferences

Tags: eclipse, download, default, restore, preferences

I have previously exported the default preferences but accidentally deleted it. Is there anywhere I can download the default set of preferences from? I am running the latest version on Mac OS X.

Thanks,
Dany.

Comment: Eclipse has many problems with color changes. I had the same problem and this plugin helped me a lot: Color Themes. I reset to default theme and solved it for me.
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to:

- do a fresh installation of your Eclipse in another directory
- export the default preferences of that instance
- import them in your existing Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks - I already tried that but it doesn't restore everything. I applied some theme by importing someone else's .epf file. Importing an original one did not restore the colours in the editor.

Comment: @DanyW: "I applied importing someone else's .epf file"... then those settings were no longer "default" ones, were they?